# Why do it still need launch notifyDataSetChanged() when I have used LiveData?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, android-jetpack

I'm learning Room with the sample project RoomWordsSample at https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-room-with-a-view/tree/kotlin.

The following code are from the project.

In my mind, the LiveDate will update UI automatically when the data changed if it was observed.

But in the file WordListAdapter.kt, I find `notifyDataSetChanged()` is added to the `function setWords(words: List<Word>)`， it's seems that it must notify UI manually when data changed.

Why do it still need launch `notifyDataSetChanged()` when I have used LiveData ?

**MainActivity.kt**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val newWordActivityRequestCode = 1
    private lateinit var wordViewModel: WordViewModel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val recyclerView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recyclerview)
        val adapter = WordListAdapter(this)
        recyclerView.adapter = adapter
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)

        wordViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(WordViewModel::class.java)


        wordViewModel.allWords.observe(this, Observer { words ->         
            words?.let { adapter.setWords(it) }
        })

    }
}
```

**WordViewModel.kt**

```
class WordViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {

    private val repository: WordRepository 
    val allWords: LiveData<List<Word>>

    init {

        val wordsDao = WordRoomDatabase.getDatabase(application, viewModelScope).wordDao()
        repository = WordRepository(wordsDao)
        allWords = repository.allWords
    }


    fun insert(word: Word) = viewModelScope.launch {
        repository.insert(word)
    }
}
```

**WordListAdapter.kt**

```
class WordListAdapter internal constructor(
        context: Context
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<WordListAdapter.WordViewHolder>() {

    private val inflater: LayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)
    private var words = emptyList<Word>() // Cached copy of words

    inner class WordViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val wordItemView: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): WordViewHolder {
        val itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_item, parent, false)
        return WordViewHolder(itemView)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: WordViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val current = words[position]
        holder.wordItemView.text = current.word
    }

    internal fun setWords(words: List<Word>) {
        this.words = words
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = words.size
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Actually, `livedata` will give you updated data in your activity. But now, it is your activity's job to update the ui. So, whenever live data gives you updated data, you will have to tell the ui to update the data. Hence, `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Comment: Thanks! How can I modify code if I hope the recyclerView UI display latest data automatically when the  livedata changed ?

Answer (score 1):

`notifyDataSetChanged` has nothing to do with `LiveData`, it's part of `RecyclerView` api.

`LiveData` - is way of receiving data in lifecycle-aware way, `RecyclerView` simply displays views.